# convert output string to map with golang

Tags: go

Get the output as

```
 {
   ARN: "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-2:xxxx:secret:team_dev-Xhzkt6",
   CreatedDate: 2018-07-05 06:50:07 +0000 UTC,
   Name: "team_dev",
   SecretString: "{\"password\":\"test\"}",
   VersionId: "6b65bfe4-7908-474b-9ae6-xxxx",
   VersionStages: ["AWSCURRENT"]
 }
```

Try to get the value as map with the key `SecretString`

```
d.Set("secret_string", output.SecretString)
```

How can I get it as [Schema TypeMap](https://www.terraform.io/docs/extend/schemas/schema-types.html#typemap)?

With `jq`, I can easily get it, but not sure how to do this in golang.

#### Updates

Thanks, @mkopriva

in the aws sdk (github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/secretsmanager/api.go), `output (GetSecretValueOutput)` is defined as `type:"structure"`

```
type GetSecretValueOutput struct {
        _ struct{} `type:"structure"`
```

And thanks again to provide a test code, I will try it.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    secretString := "{\"password\":\"test\"}"

    sec := map[string]interface{}{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(secretString), &sec); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(sec)
}
```

[Golang Playground Try Here](https://play.golang.org/p/rYMcYZvpOvL)

Comment: If output is `map[string]interface{}`, then `output["SecretString"]`. The returned value's type will be `interface{}` so you need to type assert it to a `string`.

Comment: Thanks, let me try first

Comment: get this error: invalid operation: output["SecretString"] (type *secretsmanager.GetSecretValueOutput does not support indexing)

Comment: Then that means that output is not of [Schema TypeMap](https://www.terraform.io/docs/extend/schemas/schema-types.html#typemap).

Comment: how to convert it to map or json, same as in node `JSON.parse`

Comment: Looking at the source (https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/blob/master/service/secretsmanager/api.go#L3560) it seems you can do what you were doing in the first place but you need to dereference the field since it is a pointer. Try `d.Set("secret_string", *output.SecretString)` but first make sure it's not `nil`.

Comment: If that doesn't work for you please provide the error you are getting, also provide more info on what `d.Set` is supposed to be, ie. what's `d`'s type, what's `Set`'s signature, etc.

Comment: This is the file I try to fix (https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/blob/master/aws/data_source_aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.go#L23), the key `secret_string` from output should be map, not string.

Comment: Converting a json string into a map? https://play.golang.org/p/4rqughciyX_Z

Answer (score 10, accepted):

@mkopriva

Thanks, please answer this question, so I can vote and accept it.

With your sample code, I did fix the issue.

```
-       d.Set("secret_string", output.SecretString)
+       var sec map[string]interface{}
+       if err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(*output.SecretString), &sec); err != nil {
+               return err
+       }
+       d.Set("secret_string", sec)
```